# definition of a function and correctly calling in the parameter

Tags: python, pandas

This block of code works fine without a function definition. However when I attempt to wrap a function around it I get various errors as shown below

#function definition

```
Input_Data={'abc':abc,'def':def}

    
def test_EO4():
        for sheet_name, df in Input_Data.items():
            for index in range(len(df)):
                if str(df.loc[index,'Curve 7']).startswith('Linear'):
                    df1 = df[index+1:len(df)]
                break
            df1.loc[:,'Unnamed: 26']*=-1#change sign in x direction
            'more calculations etc'
            ....
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name,index=False, header=False)    
        # Finally, save ExcelWriter to file
        writer.save()
        return
```

#executing function

**Attempt 1**:
Pass in parameter 'Input_Data' into `test_EO4()`.

TypeError `test_EO4() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

**Attempt 2**:
Do not pass in any parameter.

UnboundLocalError: `local variable 'df1' referenced before assignment`

**Attempt 3**:
Do not pass in any parameter but define `df1=0` before function.

UnboundLocalError: `local variable 'df1' referenced before assignment`

Not sure how to proceed....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Attempt1 the problem is happening because your function test_E04 does not accept any input parameters. You can change the function signature and it should work. `def test_E04(Input_Data):`

For Attempt2 and 3, you see the df1 variable is created under an if statement, that suggests that it may not be created at all in some situations and then outside the for loop if you try to access df1 when it is not created, you get the referenced before assignment error. Hope that makes sense.